# yum Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Updates-ambari-1.x. Please verify its path and try again

Tags: updates, yum, centos6.5

To whom it may concern:

I am running CentOS 6.5 on my server.
I keep on receiving the following error when I type in yum update as the root user:

```
[root@dbtest /]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

epel/metalink                                            |  14 kB     00:00
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * passenger: mirror.hmdc.harvard.edu
   http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14]
   PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
   Trying other mirror.
   Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Updates-ambari-1.x. Please
   verify its path and try again
```

I am using these two links to assist me:
https://www.webmaster.net/fix-pycurl-error-22-the-requested-url-returned-error-404-not-found/

To the best of my knowledge the reason I think I am getting this error is because there is something wrong with the ambari.repo repository file under the /etc/yum.repos.d directory.

My question is what can I do to fix the ambari.repo file, if anything, and what can I do so that I am able to successfully perform the yum update task without any errors?

This is what is inisde the ambari.repo file. Any help can be greatly appreciated.

One more thing I would like to mention is that I made changes to the CentOS-Base.repo file

Comment: Can you paste here the contents of ambari.repo. The URL in there is either pointing to the wrong location in the server. Is this file created by you or installed as part of a package?

Comment: [ambari-1.x]
name=Ambari 1.x
baseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/GA
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/RPM-GPG-KEY/RPM-GPG-KEY-Jenkins
enabled=1
priority=1

[HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.15]
name=Hortonworks Data Platform Utils Version - HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.15
baseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.15/repos/centos6
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/RPM-GPG-KEY/RPM-GPG-KEY-Jenkins
enabled=1
priority=1

Comment: [Updates-ambari-1.x]
name=ambari-1.x - Updates
baseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/RPM-GPG-KEY/RPM-GPG-KEY-Jenkins
enabled=1
priority=1

Comment: To answer your question: Is this file created by me or installed as part of package? That I don't know. I assume it is part of of package but I could be wrong. It was like that when I saw it there initially. 

@alvits All I know was that about a month ago when I did yum update it updated without any difficulty and now I keep getting that error message every time I do a yum update.

Comment: Put things like file contents in the post not comments so you can format them.

Answer (score 1):

That URL is incorrect. A quick search online for `ambari repo` led me to [this page](https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.3/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-chap9-2.html) which seems to suggest that the correct path is now `http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.2.3.7/` and that you can get a new repo file from `http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.2.3.7/ambari.repo`.

Comment: What do you mean that URL is incorrect you mean this one:  http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Updates-ambari-1.x. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: that is what was given to me in the output.

Comment: Okay. I think I see what you are saying.

So just do these steps on my server then?

wget http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.2.3.7/ambari.repo
cp ambari.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo

Comment: or do I just change that abari.repo file with the new link and do a :wq on it?

Comment: @user3634039 Yes, follow the setup steps to get the new ambari.repo file. You can absolutely hand-edit the file instead but you will need to use the new file as reference anyway so you might as well just use the new file (unless you've modified your copy in some non-trivial way which is unlikely).

Comment: Well actually what I did was just edit the ambar.repo file with the http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.2.3.7/ and saved it and when I did yum update it worked just fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user3634039 That could very well have been the only difference. I don't know.